# Where is the newline /r/n coming from and can I get rid of it?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Here's my code

```
@{ var RS = ViewBag.RS;}
@if (!RS.eof)
{
    while (!(RS.eof))
    {
        <text>@RS[0]|@RS[0]||</text>
        RS.MoveNext();
    }
}
else
{
    @:|Sorry...nothing found.||
}
```

I'm justing wanting the contents of RS[0] |RS[0] on the page and nothing else.

For some reason a new line is being inserted BEFORE the text I want.

I am not sure why this is but I'd appreciate if anyone could help nail this down as it's affected other pages of mine before as well.

Thanks.

Edit: Also, I have this view being returned as a partial view so as far as I'm aware the contents of this should literally be the contents of the cshtml page and no header nonsense.

Comment: I've been experimenting with some formatting and turns out if i put the @if(!RS.eof) on the same line as @{ var RS ...} then it seems to remove it. This makes me think that somehow it's treating the line that contains the @{var RS...} as a text line but it shouldn't as far as I know because there's nothing outside of the brackets delineating the code section

Comment: I've also experimented w/ not ending the initial brackets and just keeping the if in the same bracket and that also works as I'd expect. It almost seems like that's the design that should be taken in this case. However I could easily see a situation where I want to create / assign a variable prior to running code and it seems odd that'd i'd need to either start a bracket, declare, end the bracket, and then start the html on the same line OR wait to create the variable until immediately before the logic check just to make sure no additional newlines are created